# MSSQL Invalid Syntax with Hibernate when using DISTINCT?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

So I have this piece of Java code:

```
final Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(expense_document.id) FROM expense_document JOIN generic_object ON expense_document.id = generic_object.id JOIN expense_document_item ON expense_document_item.document_id = expense_document.id JOIN generic_object ON expense_document_item.id = generic_object.id WHERE expense_document.client_id = :client_id").setParameter("client_id", client.getId()).setMaxResults(1000);
```

and when this code is executed I get:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

I can not find what MS SQL does not like about this query. When I am connected to MySQL, this line will not cause any problems.

Comment: Query looks fine to me. Are you sure this the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the parenthesis around the parameter to the `distinct` keyword.

Use it like this:

```
select distinct something from somewhere
```

Comment: When testing this using Squirrel against SQLServer, it actually worked with the paranthesis. But if you say that removing them fixed your problem, I'll keep the answer.

Comment: The thing about drivers said in the other answer might be onto something, whenever I get a weird error from sqlserver it's always due to the sqljdbc driver. Use jtds instead..

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks fine.. are you using an up to date driver for MSSQL?

See [how to configure hibernate config file for sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585544/how-to-configure-hibernate-config-file-for-sql-server) for supported SQL server drivers.

You should be able to do:

```
final Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT(expense_document.id) FROM expense_document JOIN generic_object ON expense_document.id = generic_object.id JOIN expense_document_item ON expense_document_item.document_id = expense_document.id JOIN generic_object ON expense_document_item.id = generic_object.id WHERE expense_document.client_id = :client_id").setParameter("client_id", client.getId()).setMaxResults(1000);
```

or

```
final Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT expense_document.id FROM expense_document JOIN generic_object ON expense_document.id = generic_object.id JOIN expense_document_item ON expense_document_item.document_id = expense_document.id JOIN generic_object ON expense_document_item.id = generic_object.id WHERE expense_document.client_id = :client_id").setParameter("client_id", client.getId()).setMaxResults(1000);
```

However, if you're using hibernate, why aren't you using HQL, JPA Query language or Criteria? That should ensure that you don't have to change SQL syntax depending upon the vendor as they *differ slightly in different flavours*. I feel using JPA with entity manager might be the way forward if you're switching between different databases as **createSqlQuery** will send the string as native SQL to the vendor.

> Hibernate EntityManager implements the programming interfaces and
>   lifecycle rules as defined by the JPA 2.0 specification
>   https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/

If you're using something like hibernate, then createSqlQuery is really good for sending vendor specific queries when you want to set hints for example.